# LSTM with Attention getting weights?? Classifing documents based on sentence embedding

Tags: python, keras, lstm, attention-model

I'm really stuck building a NN for text-classification with `keras` using `lstm` and adding an `attention_layer` on top. Im sure Iam pretty close, but Im confused:

- **Do I have to add a `TimeDistributed` dense layer after LSTM?**
- **And, how do I retrieve the Attention weights from my network (for visualization purpose)?** - so that I know which sentence was 'responsible' that the document was classified as *good* or *bad*?

Say, I have 10 documents consisting of 100 sentences and each sentence is represented as a 500 element vector. So my documents matrix containing the sentence-sequences looks like: `X = np.array(Matrix).reshape(10, 100, 500)`

The documents should be classified to an according sentiment 1=good; 0=bad - so

```
y= [1,0,0,1,1]
yy= np.array(y)
```

I dont need an embedding-layer cause each sentence of each document is already a sparse-vector.

The attention layer is taken from: https://github.com/richliao/textClassifier/blob/master/textClassifierHATT.py

```
MAX_SENTS = 100
MAX_SENT_LENGTH = 500

review_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTS, MAX_SENT_LENGTH))
l_lstm_sent = LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(review_input)
l_att_sent = AttLayer(100)(l_lstm_sent)
preds = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(l_att_sent)
model = Model(review_input, preds)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(X, yy, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=50)
```

So I *think* my model should be set up correctly but Im not quite sure.. But how do I get the attention-weights from that (e.g. so I know which sentence caused a classification as 1)? Help so much appreciated

Comment: Is it just running another model after ```model=Model(review_input, preds)```? Like: ```attmodel = Model(review_input, outputs=[preds, l_att_sent])``` and then fitting the ```model``` an running ```predictions, att_weights = attmodel.predict(X)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Time distributed**

In this case, you don't have to wrap `Dense` into [`TimeDistributed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed?version=stable), although it may be a little bit faster if you do, especially if you can provide a mask that masks out a large part of the LSTM output.

However, `Dense` operates in the last dimension no matter what the shape before the last dimension is.

**2. Attention weights**

Yes, it is as you suggest in the comment. You need to modify the `AttLayer` it is capable of returning both its output and the attention weights.

```py
return output, ait
```

And then create a model that contains both prediction and attention weight tensors and get the predictions for them:

```py
l_att_sent, l_att_sent = AttLayer(100)(l_lstm_sent)
...
predictions, att_weights = attmodel.predict(X)
```